# Can I use Visual Studio's Data Source Configuration Wizard to connect to the YouTube api?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, youtube

Can I use the Data Source Configuration Wizard in Visual C# 2010 Express to connect to a YouTube api feed or is there something I don't understand (which is probable)?

I'm writing a WPF app in C# and would like to bind a listbox to an atom feed like:

[YouTube](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated)

If not, why is the YouTube api not compatible with the Source Configuration Wizard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can. You can however use [SyndicationFeed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx) (3.5+), like so:

```
XmlReader Reader = XmlReader.Create("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/top_rated");
SyndicationFeed Feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(Reader);

foreach (var Item in Feed.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Item.Title.Text);
    Console.WriteLine(Item.Id);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Reader.Close();
```

EDIT: to answer your question as to why it doesn't work these links may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2t4x15.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dd7z6t.aspx. I think it just comes down to Atom isn't a supported data source.